# Options available to a programmer on the Main Game Loop

Tags: physics, graphics, game-loop, frame-rate

Could someone please give me some insight into each one of the four topics listed below.

I have a good idea about what passive and active rendering are, and that the use of active rendering is more suitable for games programming.

I'm just not to sure about the rest.

---

The timing of the main game loop is an important component of any computer game, since it impacts on the frame rate and the real-time physics calculations needed to make the game run at a realistic (or at least playable) rate. You are required to read up on the programming issues that affect this timing, and write a report that covers the range 
of options available to a programmer. Your report should consider the following headings:

1. The distinction between active and passive rendering, and an explanation of the preferred mode for a game program.
2. The division of time between the physics (or game-model) update and graphics update stages, and an explanation and analysis of the relative importance of these in a game that involves real-time physics calculations.
3. Techniques for achieving accuracy in real-time physics, and an explanation of the trade-offs that may be necessary to do this.
4. Programming techniques that can be used to try to keep the frame-rate for graphics updates to some desired rate.

Comment: Is this homework?  Additionally a more clear, specific question would attract better responses.

Comment: It's homework and sorry I really should have made it more clear of what I was asking.

What I am looking for are respones to each 4 numbered points, for example the distinction of active and passive rendering, where passive is graphics updated in the paint() method etc. I am trying to gain a better knowledge of this subject, but I am finding difficult to find any information. 

So any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you guys for responding.

Comment: Those are all pretty broad, and would be better suited to fewer, focused questions instead of trying to lump them all into one.

Comment: Closing for now as not a real question.  If you want further help, feel free to ask more directed, specific, individual questions.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this question asked elsewhere; I can't remember where.  A response gave this link:

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

It describes the advantages and disadvantages of different techniques for calculating time, and how to sync graphics and physics updates when they run at different rates.  It's very well written and provides code samples.

Comment: I think you meant that you've seen ***part 4*** of this question asked elsewhere.